# P-Cell installation (FreePDK45)

Tags: python, cadence, cadence-virtuoso

I am trying to make [these instructions](http://www.eda.ncsu.edu/wiki/FreePDK45:Using_P-Cells) work. I am having some difficulties along the way, it would be of great help if you could point me to the right direction!

I have tried to follow the instructions in the web site. I did not quite understood the step 2 and 3.

> add the Python path to the first line of each script in this directory

I am not sure which python path is this. Is this `$PDK_DIR/ncsu_basekit/gentech/sshaft/bin`? And after trying a while, it seemed have created a `bin` folder: `$PDK_DIR/ncsu_basekit/gentech/bin` and copied all `*.py` files here.

While updating the `icoa_setup.csh`, I have found that, I also needed to `source` the `setup.csh` file as well, otherwise the `NCSU_TechLib_FreePDK45` or `NCSU_Devices_FreePDK45` library do not load in Cadence Virtuoso.

Finally, when I run the command `gentech.py -log gen.log` from `$PDK_DIR/ncsu_basekit/gentech`, I am getting the following error:

```
/home/class/ahmed589/NCSU-FreePDK45-1.4/FreePDK45/ncsu_basekit/gentech/sshaft/bin/gentech.py: Permission denied
```

Probably because: the first line of the `gentech.py` is not an executable file, rather a folder

```
#!/home/class/ahmed589/NCSU-FreePDK45-1.4/FreePDK45/ncsu_basekit/gentech/sshaft/src/py/
```

if the line is changed to

```
#!/home/class/ahmed589/NCSU-FreePDK45-1.4/FreePDK45/ncsu_basekit/gentech/sshaft/src/py/gentech.py
```

then the following error message is found:

```
import: Command not found.
Badly placed ()'s.
```

Maybe the following info would be helpful:

- Operating system: `Linux 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64`
- Cadence Virtuoso version `6.1.5`
- oaGetVersion : `22.41.004`
- Pycell studio version : `2014.09-L4 of PyCell Studio`
- PyCell Studio build with Python version: `2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 7 2011, 14:30:04) [GCC 4.4.3]`

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes down you your misunderstanding of the instruction to "add the Python path to the first line of each script in this directory".  This is the *path to the Python executable* which should be used in executing your scripts

The first line of your script should be changed from --

```
#!/home/class/ahmed589/NCSU-FreePDK45-1.4/FreePDK45/ncsu_basekit/gentech/sshaft/src/py/
```

-- to reference *that* path; which is likely to be the output of --

```
which python
```

-- e.g., --

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```